# Deploying Spree to Heroku

Tags: heroku, rubygems, spree

To deploy spree to heroku , I followed the guidline in https://github.com/krozen20/Spree-version-0.11.0/blob/master/spree.txt
  when typing "git push heroku master"
  it shows me this message

---

Installing gem chronic 0.2.3 from http://rubygems.org 
       ERROR:  Error installing chronic: 
     hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself. 
   !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gem 
  To git@heroku.com:krozentest.git 
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) 
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:krozentest.git'

---

mind asking here what I have done wrong? any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a disparity between your version of Rubygems and the one on Heroku.  I would update your local Rubygems (`gem update --system`) and then re-bundle install.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with his *local* RubyGems, but rather the one that's on the Heroku stack. Hard to tell.

Comment: Ah, could be - just checked one of my Heroku dynos and it's telling me Rubygems is at 1.3.7